# get the all feeds data in single array in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, loops

i have one doubt in the node js
i need to get the data from the rss feed
for that i install the rss-parser module in it
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser

let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser();

```
(async () => {

  let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
  console.log(feed.title);

  feed.items.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
  });

})();
```

the code was like that
here they are using the async function
to get the data feed for one url
i have lot of urls
i need to loop it and get the feed details in single array
is there any posibility
please tell me is there any thing
i need to get the all feed url details in a single array

I tried as of now this

I tried this code

```
exports.getRssFeedLinks = () => {
    // Setting URL and headers for request

    // Return new promise 
    return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
        // Do async job
        let getSql = 'SELECT * FROM `news_feeds`';
        //console.log(updateSql);
        connection.query(getSql, (error, results, fileds) => {
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            else {
                returnResult = JSON.stringify(results);
                fulfill(returnResult);
            }
        });
    })
}

exports.errHandler = function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}

exports.getRssFeeds = (req, res) => {
    let parser = new Parser();
    let feedLink;

    var dataPromise = this.getRssFeedLinks();
    //console.log(dataPromise);
    dataPromise.then(JSON.parse, this.errHandler)
    .then(function(newFeeds) {
        // Do one more async operation here
        let feedsList = []; 
        if(newFeeds && newFeeds.length > 0)  {
            let feedLinks = [];
            newFeeds.forEach(feed => {
              feedLinks.push(feed.link);  
            });
            (async () => {
                let feeds = await Promise.all(feedLinks.map(parser.parseURL));
                //feeds will have array of arrays, each array includes the response feed from each url

                feeds = [].concat(...feeds) //if you want to flatten the array
                feed.forEach(({item}) => {
                    console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
                });

                feeds.forEach(feed => {
                    console.log(feed.title);

                    feed.items.forEach(item => {
                        console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
                    });
                })
            })();
               } 

            if(feedsList.length >0) {                
                res.send({
                    "success" : true,
                    "result" : feedsList
                });
            }
            else {
                res.send({
                    "success" : true,
                    "message" : "No Record ",
                    "result" : feedsList
                });
            }


    }, this.errHandler);   


}
```

***Errors
(node:5700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property
'options' of undefined
(node:5700) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.***

Comment: Did you already try something yourself? You could just do a loop foreach URL, call the async function in there and then use [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the result to your "single array"

Comment: i placed what ever i tried in that

Comment: i tried as per your concent but its return  before collecting all the feed datas

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` to send multiple request.

```
(async () => {
    let feeds = await Promise.all(['https://www.reddit.com/.rss1', 'https://www.reddit.com/.rss2'].map(parser.parseURL));
    //feeds will have array of arrays, each array includes the response feed from each url

    feeds = [].concat(...feeds) //if you want to flatten the array
    feed.forEach(({item}) => {
        console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
    });

    //or use loop through each feed

    feeds.forEach(feed => {
        console.log(feed.title);

        feed.items.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
        });
    })
})();
```

Comment: Now i edited the question with what i tried with your code but i dot this error

Comment: why you are using both loops I have given you both options, you can choose any not both, remove the part of code after comment `or use loop.....`

Comment: i cannot see the problem with statement `some error` what error you are getting and what have you tried?

Comment: Same error comming again no luck, I used the rss-parser npm [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser)

Comment: (node:5700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined 
mysql node.js loops

Comment: (node:5700) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.